# React useState hook not updating within async useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I want to overwrite **user** with the object I saved in localStorage, but its not working.

Note, component is called *Index* because I'm using next.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { loadUser } from '../utils/user';

const Index = () => {
  const [ user, setUser ] = useState({});

  async function restore(){
    const loadedUser = await loadUser();
    console.log(loadedUser);                    // correct - {userId: 4124783261364}
    setUser(loadedUser); 
    console.log(user);                          // was not updated - {}
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    restore();
  }, [0])

  return (<></>);
};

export default Index;
```

Comment: State Updates May Be Asynchronous. You can't get the updated user right after setUser.
React may batch multiple setState() calls into a single update for performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issues

- If you want to run an effect and clean it up **only once** (on **mount** and **unmount**), you can pass an empty array (**`[]`**) (**not `[0]`**), as a second argument. This tells React that your effect **doesn’t depend on any values** from props or state, so it **never** needs to **re-run**.
- **Much like setState in Class components** created by extending React.Component or React.PureComponent, the state update using the updater provided by **useState hook is also asynchronous**, and **will not be reflected immediately**. That's **why** `console.log(user);` **doesn't show updated value** next to `setUser(loadedUser);`

### Solution

```
  const restore = async () => {
    const loadedUser = await loadUser();
    console.log(loadedUser);                    // correct - {userId: 4124783261364}
    setUser(loadedUser); 
    console.log(user);                          // user is not updated here, but will be
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    restore();
  }, []);
```

### Similar Situation

This is **away from your problem** since you just need to load user from local storage just one time. But when `loadUser()` returns **changing results** by time so need to update user real time, you should use **`useCallback`**.

```
  const updateUser = useCallback(async () => {
    const loadedUser = await loadUser();
    setUser(loadedUser); 
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    updateUser();
  }, [updateUser]);
```

Comment: Thanks @softengineer123, I didn't know setState was async. That explains why I noticed it console logging later on. Also, I had started with an empty dep array but added the 0 dep to see if it would help. I'll revert.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
// Assuming your loadUser() functions is set like the line below
const loadedUser = {userID: '513216351354'};


const Index = () => {

function restore(){
  console.log("Loaded user is " + loadedUser.userID);       // Loaded user is 513216351354
  setUser(loadedUser.userID); 
  console.log("User is " + user);                          // User is 513216351354
};

useEffect(() => {
  restore();
}, [])

return (<></>);
}

export default Index;
```

Comment: I don't see how this would resolve the issue of setUser being async. Also, user needs to be an object because it will eventually have more properties.